# Android Studio Export Vector Drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

Is it possible to do the reverse process of importing .svg file to vector drawable in Android Studio? https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

I'm working with legacy code, and the designer guy needs an icon sample from our application. I sent him the xml files of vector drawable in Android Studio, but he says he don't know about xml file.

Comment: see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp), you can try it online [here](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_path)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948396/convert-vectordrawable-to-svg

Comment: Thanks @VladyslavUlianytskyi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert VectorDrawable to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948396/convert-vectordrawable-to-svg)