# Convert VectorDrawable to SVG

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have made the opposite conversions (SVG to `VectorDrawable`) manually or using web tools.

But I am having hard time to do the opposite thing. I have `VectorDrawable` but I am not sure how to convert it to SVG and I can find zero online tools to do it.

Does anyone have experience with this and what are the steps or tools to do it?

Answer (score 207):

Steps I follow:

`android:pathData` replaced with `d`

`android:fillColor` replaced with `fill`

`android:strokeColor` replaced with `stroke`

`android:strokeWidth` replaced with `stroke-width`

`android:fillType` replaced with `fill-rule`

A path in the VectorDrawable without `fillColor` is `fill="none"` in SVG.

`android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"` is `viewBox="0 0 24 24"` in SVG.

**Example**

Vector Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M12,3L2,12h3v8h2.5v-0.8c0-1.5,3-2.2,4.5-2.2s4.5,0.8,4.5,2.2V20H19v-8h3L12,3zM12,15.2c1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2 s1-2.2,2.2-2.2s2.2,1,2.2,2.2S13.2,15.2,12,15.2z" />
    <path android:pathData="M0,0h24v24H0V0z" />
</vector>
```

SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24" 
    height="24" 
    viewBox="0 0 24 24" >

    <path 
        fill="#ffffff"
        d="M12,3L2,12h3v8h2.5v-0.8c0-1.5,3-2.2,4.5-2.2s4.5,0.8,4.5,2.2V20H19v8h3L12,3zM12,15.2c1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2 s1-2.2,2.2-2.2s2.2,1,2.2,2.2S13.2,15.2,12,15.2z" />
    <path d="M0,0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That was a great help, but your SVG is missing the closing tag I think. Otherwise doesn't seem to validate, or open in Illustrator.

Comment: XSLT can help to automate this job. It's pretty simple, but I don't know how to handle prefix "android:" for attributes. So, I remove all occurrences of "android:" and then transform vector drawable to raw SVG. Here is [XSL](https://gist.github.com/ok3141/1285e56f44d7e47b9a22e664406a5fab) template; I tried it [on this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) and it works for me.

Comment: what does tint: in vector drawable map to in svg?

Comment: color "FF000000" is not working, should be change to "000000"

Comment: One more: `android:fillType` is `fill-rule` in **SVG**

Comment: Another for the list:  the android <group> tag is <g> in SVG, and if you want to handle android:translateX or android:translateY you'll need to use the transform="translate()" attribute in its place.

Comment: https://www.joydeepdeb.com/tools/find-replace.html might come in handy for this solution

Comment: In my case it working it convert to svg online https://shapeshifter.design/

Comment: `android:fillAlpha` is `fill-opacity`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042577/3151675

Answer (score 56):

The **VectorDrawable** format is pretty similar to **SVG**.

You can find the documentation of the **VectorDrawable** format [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html), and the documentation of the **SVG** format [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/).

I just written [this Python script](https://gitlab.com/Hyperion777/VectorDrawable2Svg) which converts a vector drawable xml, to a svg.
It doesn't cover all the vector drawable proprieties, but it works with the most common ones.
You have only to drop your xml files onto the script, and the files will be converted.

Comment: its for linux? drop nothing does

Comment: @СергейГрушин I tried the script on Windows but it should work on Linux too. You should check if there is an error into the console. Maybe the xml module it's not installed? In this case you should run `pip install xml`

Comment: script works only in command-line. Thanks. But I want drag&drop, so I create desktop shortcut with `Exec=python /opt/utils/xml2svg.py %U` Now I can drag files and drop him on the desktop shortcut :) Also I edited 2 things: now script delete source xml files after converting, svg file name now without `.xml` pre-extension.

Comment: FYI, @Hyperion, I forked your repository to add better handling of colours: https://github.com/RohanTalip/VectorDrawable2Svg

Comment: Thanks for the py script!

Comment: I made a really simple website just to do that. https://vd.floo.app/