# Convert Vector Drawable to SVG

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

Is there any tool to convert Vector Drawable to SVG? I lost my original svg file and now I would like to reduce the size of the image. Currently, I have,

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1200dp"
    android:height="1200dp"
    android:viewportHeight="1200"
    android:viewportWidth="1200">
```

I would like to make it 180x180. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to remove some points on your path? change them somehow? or just "scale down"?

Comment: I just wanna scale it down.

Comment: so this is pointless - it does not matter how big your `android:viewportWidth` / `android:viewportHeight` are, as the vector drawable is scalable and can be drawn with any size on the target canvas

Comment: Cant you just edit and width to `800dp` to reduce its size?

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But I am having inflationexception due to using such a big image. There are quite a few posts in stackoverflow.

Comment: what exception? post the stacktrace

Comment: InflateException @pskink

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: Does the solution have to be trough code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this [Convert VectorDrawable to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948396/convert-vectordrawable-to-svg)

The Vector Drawable format is pretty similar to SVG. With just a few modifications you can turn your xml drawable back to SVG

Credits to this guy who made this python script that coverts xml drawables back to SVG https://gitlab.com/Hyperion777/VectorDrawable2Svg

Answer (score 18):

Look at this [Shapeshifter](https://shapeshifter.design/)

Shapeshifter tool can import VectorDrawable XML file and export back to SVG file

Comment: By far the fastest and easiest solution

Comment: For me it didn't support gradients (`<gradient>` tag in vector drawable), so I couldn't use it in my case