# How to Convert Vector Paths to Image and Vice-Versa

Tags: android, xml, vector, path, drawable

Android likes drawables to be vector paths now like this:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="140.0"
        android:viewportWidth="140.0" android:width="24dp" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <path android:fillAlpha="0.15" android:fillColor="#00000000"
          android:pathData="M45.58,145L45.58,-3"
          android:strokeAlpha="0.15" 
          android:strokeColor="#333333" 
          android:strokeWidth="24"/>

</vector>
```

However, making paths by hand becomes very overwhelming very quickly!

What tools are there to 1) take an image and export it as a path, and 2) take a path like above, render it as an image, and allow the image to be manipulated so the new path can be exported via 1?

I've been looking and looking and I can't figure out how to get these vectors. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need an image (`.png` preferred) what you want.

Then convert it to SVG. You can use an online converter for it

After that, u need to convert that SVG to vector drawable. u can use this link http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/ for it.

Make sure that u need to provide e compatible image for it. otherwise your vector drawable may not be same as u expected

This [easiest way to use svg in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923205/easiest-way-to-use-svg-in-android) contains other alternative solutions that you can use.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly for converting SVG to Vector path!!

Do you know how to take a given path and turn it into an image so the image can be modified?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948396/convert-vectordrawable-to-svg will help for u. you need to convert it to SVG first. 
Then png. Please mark the answer as accepted. if it is help for u. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio allows for creating your own vector drawables from svg files. For converting path to image, I guess you can show drawable on Imageiew and capture it - you can do it pragmatically. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot).

Comment: Yes, the pragmatic way is possible, I was hoping there might be a program, since it's a path, that if you load it in, it would give you the nodes so the image can be manipulated and a new path exported cleanly. Are you aware of any?