# Is there any way to export app icon out of android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there anyway I can export the app icon created in Android studio out of Android studio for editing in Photoshop?

Comment: If you have the project, the icon is either an image or a vector drawable in the res/drawable directory.  Just open the file.  If you don't know which on it is, it will be named in the manifest

Comment: But as far as I know you can't edit and XML in Photoshop

Comment: You can if its in svg format.  A description of how to convert it to SVG is here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948396/convert-vectordrawable-to-svg  Or I'm sure you can find a script to do it.

Comment: @Whoyoumecallit Right-click on your app icon folder and click on `Open In`>`Explorer` then you redirect to your icon folder.

Comment: If I could accept a comment as an answer I would accept @GabeSechan answer
It worked for me.